# C++, fstream works fine but the file always is empty?

Tags: c++, fstream, xilinx

I have some complex data to store into file, I am working in **vitis Xilinx IDE**.

I tried this :

```
using namespace std;
ofstream strm_out;
      strm_out.open("results.txt");
if(!strm_out.is_open()) {
    cout << "failed to open strm_out"<<endl;
    return 1;
}
for(int i = 0 ; i < SAMPLES_NUM; i++){
    double Re, Im;
    Re = out[2 * i];
    Im = out[2 * i + 1];
    strm_out << setprecision(12) << Re << "+(" << Im <<"i)"<<endl;
    strm_out.flush();
}
strm_out.close();

ifstream strm_in;
strm_in.open("results.txt");
if(!strm_in.is_open()) {
    cout << "failed to open strm_in"<<endl;
    return 1;
}
string line;
while(getline(strm_in, line)) {
    cout << line << endl;
}
strm_in.close();
```

It works correctly as I get printed all the stored data, but when I go to check the file manually I find it empty and its **size** is `0 bytes`.

What could be the issue here?!

The file path, as you see, is located at the same location as the source code.

I'm sure the Read and Write permission on the file are correct.

I got into this issue before, and I can't remember how I solved it.

I hope I can get any help here.

Comment: I suspect that your application's working directory is not what you think it is. Check your IDE settings.

Comment: There is no guarantee that this code will read and write to the same location as the source code. On any system I have ever used the location of the source code is completely irrelevant. Instead you need to find out what the current working directory is for your system. Try deleting the empty file, does it get recreated when you rerun the program?

Comment: I would suggest testing with absolute paths, just to be sure it is not some configuration problem in your IDE.

Comment: In my experience the path is always relative to the executable, so try to look in the directory where your IDE places the compiled binary.

Comment: Yes, that's true, I found out that is not storing in that file same location as source code, I need to find where the IDE is placing it.

Comment: *"need to find where the IDE is placing it"*  One way is to **tell** the program where to put the file, by giving it a path and not just a filename.

Comment: I tried to put whole path, for some reason the fstream fails to open the file, I tried `strm_out.open("/home/user/workspace/results.txt");` and it returns *false*

Comment: @A.A. -- Then remove all the code, and run a simple `main`: `int main() { std::ostream strm_out("/home/user/workspace/results.txt"); }` -- If that does not create a file, then there is something fundamental that is outside of C++ for that file not being able to be created.  If not that, you have a serious issue with your runtime library.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie - A simple code `int main() { std::ofstream strm_out("/home/user/workspace/results.txt"); }` doesn't create the file. And I could create it using another environment with C++. I think the problem is with the current **Xilinx Vitis** environment, which I don't know a lot about it .